# Best way to provide a secure external webpage for importing to an internal database and Django. (Best way for the tiers to comunicate).

Tags: django, architecture, n-tier-architecture, non-relational-database

I have an Django application at my work, only available on the internal network.

Currently we import data using Excel, but this is a terrible error prone process and I want to replace it.

I would like to provide a rich web application in Javascript which exposes some, but not all of the data  from the main Django application (lookup values for menus). This would run on a server visible to the outside world.

So what is a good approach for this?

Management are concerned about security of making the main Django app available to the outside world, and I would prefer an intermediate tier as well - I think it would be easier to write a small server side app than to go through the current code and make sure it is secure enough to the outside world (I learned Django buildiong this app, so some of the older code is not done according to best practices, but does work as it needs to). I would also like it to hold the new data until someone has checked it looks OK before importing to the main database. (I am the only developer, so there are time considerations).

So two options I can think of just now.

1: Have a small Django app on an external facing server. This can communicate with the main app to get the values required for lookups, and store the input before it gets imported. The tables will essentially mirror the main app and need updated when the main app tables change.

2: Have something similar, but rather than use a database, use the external facing server to contact the REST interface on the internal server. Something like using Django non-relational to get data from the REST interface of the main app. Put an import table in the main database server to store the dats for approval.

Are either of these good / bad approaches?
Any other suggestions? 
Are there any good resources for learning about n-tier apps?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly  you want a small Group of trusted users to be able to access an internal database. There is already an Internal Django App accessing that database.

Management is concerned about making this app or an extension of it available to the general Internet.

I think ther concerns are very valid. If you have only a limited set of users accessing the import functionality, push authentication out of the Django Web Application into the HTTP Server / Balancer / Frontend.

For example set up an apache external webserver forcing all access to your Django App beeing encrypted (HTTPS) and authenticated. Users can be authenticated via HTTP-Auth using static files on the server. Password changes / user additions have to be done by an admin logging into the server.

Only after completing this login the Django App with it's own authentication can be accessed. I would opt vor a smale seperate import App instead of extending the main app. This small app could run with reduced permissions on the main database for an defense in depth aproach.

This setup provides you with a litte additional interfaces / points of failures, while maintaining a small attack surface against random Internet users. You can hire a security consultant th audit your apache config and be assured that you locked out the greater Internet and only have to worry about HTTP-Authenticated users.

I have benn running such setups for 15 years by now. Users are annoyed by the double authentication and password saving in Internet Cafes *is* an issue whith HTTP-Auth but generally it is verry seamless if once set up.

Comment: I solved this years ago, by creation a separate Django app on the public network, data being synced / pulled from the main application on the internal network.